# Yield hold until other line > 0

Tags: python, yield, simpy

I'm using SimPy 2.3 and have a process which generates customers at an ATM at a random rate and another process which serves customers at a random rate. When the line is empty I want the ATM to wait for the next customer before doing anything else.

Here's some code

```
class ATM(Process):
    def Run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.atm_line.customers is 0:
                yield hold, wait for self.atm_line.customers != 0 # this is the line I'm stuck on
            yield hold, self, random.expovariate(.1)
            self.atm_line.customers -= 1

class ATM_Line(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers = 0
        Process.__init__(self)

    def Run(self):
        while 1:
            yield hold, self, random.expovariate(.1)
            self.customers += 1

initialize()
a = ATM()
a.atm_line = ATM_Line()
activate(a, a.Run())
activate(a.atm_line, a.atm_line.Run())
simulate(until=10000)
```

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Your pseudocode makes it very hard to answer. Where does `line` come from? Is there something we can loop over that generates `line` (and maybe `hold` and `wait`)?

Comment: Sorry should be more clear now hopefully. Line is just one instance of ATM_Line and can't be iterated over.

Comment: You've created an attribute named `a.line`, changed one instance of `line` to be `self.atm_line`, and left the other one as `line`, which is still not at all clear. Also, I'm not sure what all your non-Python code is supposed to be doing. Is the ATM process really supposed to be making the line longer each time through the loop, or does your `++` not mean the same thing as in C? Can you just write this as actual Python, and with consistent variable names, instead of making us guess at it?

Comment: Sorry guess I shouldn't half-ass when I code. Should be updated now to clearly reflect the intentions of the program. The ATM class is decrementing the atm_line.customers int on each loop while the attached ATM_Class in incrementing the customers int on each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using yield waitevent and signals. The working code is below.

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from random import Random, expovariate, uniform

class ATM(Process):
    def Run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.atm_line.customers is 0:
                yield waitevent, self, self.atm_line.new_customer
            yield hold, self, random.expovariate(.05)
            self.atm_line.customers -= 1

class ATM_Line(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers = 0
        self.new_customer = SimEvent()
        Process.__init__(self)

    def Run(self):
        while 1:
            yield hold, self, random.expovariate(.07)
            self.new_customer.signal()
            self.customers += 1

initialize()
a = ATM()
a.atm_line = ATM_Line()
activate(a, a.Run())
activate(a.atm_line, a.atm_line.Run())
simulate(until=50)
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, and you think it would be useful to others with similar problems, remember to accept your own answer.